# Bash script for monitor the API json response

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, sh

I want to monitor the below health check URL. I need generate a alert if mongodb goes to disconnected state. I wrote a bash script. Seems its still not working. Any can help on this ? Thanks

When do health check to https://www.example.com/healthz result as below response: `{"mongodb":"connected","redis":"connected"}`

My bash script is

```
#!/bin/bash
DATA=$(wget --timeout 5 -O - -q -t 1 example.com/healthz)
MESSAGE=$(jq '.Disconnected' <<< "$DATA")
if [[ "$MESSAGE" == '"Success"' ]] ;
```

Comment: And my Bash script is:

#!/bin/bash
    DATA=$(wget --timeout 5 -O - -q -t 1 https://www.example.com/healthz)
    MESSAGE=$(jq '.Disconnected' <<< "$DATA")
if [[ "$MESSAGE" == '"Success"' ]] ;  then
    echo something
else
    send email

Comment: That needs to go (properly formatted) in your question, not a comment.

Comment: Hi Thanks shawn. Im new to this .when i try to add it it gives errors.will try to add it .Thanks

Comment: Crossposting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/575531/74329

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of possible use of `jq` is this:

```
jq '.mongodb == "disconnected" or .redis == "disconnected"'
```

(it will return `true` or `false`).

You can find the documentation of `js` e.g. here: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual